# Difference Between Residual Neural Net and Recurrent Neural Net?

Tags: neural-networks

What is the difference between a **Residual** Neural Net and a **Recurrent** Neural Net?

As I understand,

[Residual Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf) are very deep networks that implement 'shortcut' connections across multiple layers in order to preserve context as depth increases. Layers in a residual neural net have input from the layer before it and the optional, less processed data, from *X* layers higher. This prevents early or deep layers from 'dying' due to converging loss.

[Recurrent Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03640.pdf) are networks that contain a directed cycle which when computed is 'unrolled' through time. Layers in recurrent neural network have input from the layer before it and the optional, *time dependent* extra input. This provides situational context for things like natural language processing.

Therefor, a recurrent neural network can be used to generate a basic residual network if the input remains the same with respect to time.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is YES, they basically are the same according to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03640v1)

[image]

The figure above shows how they compared both and how a ResNet can be reformulated into a recurrent form tat is almost identical to a RNN.
For more info you can read the paper and get deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is true:

- **Recurrent neural networks (RNN)** generally refer to the type of neural network architectures, where the input to a neuron can also include additional data input, along with the activation of the previous layer. E.g. for real-time handwriting or speech recognition.
- **Residual neural networks (ResNet)** refer to another type of neural network architecture, where the input to a neuron can include the activations of two (or more) of its predecessors. E.g. for non-realtime handwriting or speech recognition.

So, there is a difference but maybe these implementations can be considered equivalent, especially if we are performing non-real-time data analysis.